# TypeORM - Running a migration with custom schema

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm, monorepo, node.js-typeorm

I need to run TypeORM migration that creates bunch of tables. MS-SQL Database is already created. Those tables are part of schema `domain1`. Here's the ORM config and migration.

**config**

```
return {
   type: 'mssql',
   host: '..',
   port: '..',
   username: '..',
   password: '..',
   database: '..',
   options: {
     encrypt: true,
   },
   entities: [`${__dirname}/src/entities/*.entity{.ts,.js}`],
   migrations: [`${__dirname}/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}`],
   migrationsRun: true,
   synchronize: false,
   logging: true,
   schema: 'domain1',
   cli: {
     migrationsDir: 'apps/myapp/src/migration',
   },
};
```

**migration:**

```
export class addBasicSchema1411753217156 implements MigrationInterface {
  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
     console.log('inside up method');
     await queryRunner.createSchema('domain1', true);

     await queryRunner.query(
        `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables t JOIN sys.schemas s ON (t.schema_id = s.schema_id) WHERE s.name = 'domain1' AND t.name = 'table1') CREATE TABLE "domain1".[table1] (..);`,
     );
     await queryRunner.query(
        `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables t JOIN sys.schemas s ON (t.schema_id = s.schema_id) WHERE s.name = 'domain1' AND t.name = 'table2') CREATE TABLE "domain1".[table2] (..);`,
     );
  }

  public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
     await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE "domain1"."table1"`);
     await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE "domain1"."table2"`);
     await queryRunner.dropSchema('domain1', true);
  }
}
```

The problem here is, it tries to create migration table with schema like `domain1.migration` **before the schema gets created**. Flow never reaches to `console.log('inside up method');`

```
CREATE TABLE "mydb"."domain1"."migrations" ("id" int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), "timestamp" bigint NOT NULL, 
"name" varchar(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "PK_8b82d7f526340ab734260ea46b1" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))
```

and throws the error:
 `QueryFailedError: Error: The specified schema name "domain1" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not have permission to create a new schema (or Database).

I faced a similar issue, and I solved it by creating the Database manually.

The root cause of my case was that the user I configured in the `typeorm` **doesn't have permission to create the schema**.

Answer (score 0):

The error actually states the problem. The schema/database `domain1` does not exist or the user you have passed doesn't have the rights to work with it.

Please check that you have the database created in MySQL, you could try using MySQL Workbench as a GUI application. If it is not there then create it.

Also, there is a question regarding the user you are using to connect to the database. You could try creating a new user and grant him access to the schema, but most likely the schema is not created.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a little bit old, but I faced the same problem as you and almost give up from the project.

So, for me the problem was because I was setting the name of the schema on DataSource configuration, and when the typeorm run the migration he tries to connect with the default schema setted on DataSource configuration, and as it doesn't exists the connection fails and when i changed the schema name from DataSource to public, as it already exists the migrations runned successfully.

I ho this answer can help you.